# Swift - From Dictionary to NSManagedObject

Tags: dictionary, struct, swift, nsmanagedobject

I was trying to get value from a dictionary and set attributes class with their values

this is what I have done:

```
class myClass : NSManagedObject{
@NSManaged var remoteId:NSNumber
@NSManaged var creationDate:NSDate
@NSManaged var title:String
@NSManaged var total:NSNumber

func fromDictionary(dictionary:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
{
    if let x:Int = dictionary["id"]! as? Int {
        remoteId = NSNumber(integer: x)
    }
    if let x:String = dictionary["creation_date"]! as? String {
        creationDate = x.formattedDate()
    }
    if let x:Double = dictionary["total"]! as? Double {
        total = NSNumber(double: x)
    }
    if let x:String = dictionary["title"]! as? String {
        title = x
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to optimize or to do this function in a more generic way, in order to be easily usable with other classes

Until now I attempted to use enum (to enumerate the dictionary keys, but It seems to me the wrong way)

I was trying to have something like that

```
enum keyTypes {
   case int
   case currency
   case text
   case bool
   case date
}

struct fields {
   var keyName:String
   var keyType:keyTypes
}
```

then

```
var xx = fields[]()
xx.append(fields("id",keyTypes.int))
xx.append(fields("creationDate",keyTypes.int))
...
```

and the looping this array.

do you have a better idea?